# How can I change terminals command line color?

Tags: command-line, terminal, zsh

I found that this terminal is so beautiful. But I don't know how to configure it.
In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=1969&v=sz_dsktIjt4&feature=youtu.be), you can see that the command and argument are in different colors like this

[image: like this].

I'm developing on macOS and zsh, could someone help me please! Thanks so much!

Comment: google "configure mac terminal colors"

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=terminal+colour or https://superuser.com/search?q=terminal+color